# Using closure for private variables in coffeescript

Tags: closures, coffeescript, private

In JavaScript, one would define a private member variable by making it a local variable in a function that returns a closure:

```
var count = (function(){
  var i = 0;
  return function (){ return i++; }
})();
```

This involves a define-function-then-call-it idiom that is fairly common in JavaScript, but I do not know how it translates in CoffeeScript. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `do` keyword

```
count = do ->
  i = 0
  -> i++
```

Comment: Works even without the 'do', a working one-liner would be 
`count = -> i = 0; -> i++`

Comment: @JacobOscarson No it doesn't... If you leave out the `do` and call `count()`, it returns a function.  If you include the `do` and call `count()` it returns an incrementing integer.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian said, the `do` keyword is best. You can also use parens, just as in JavaScript:

```
count = (->
  i = 0
  -> i++
)()
```